# Django URLconf: getting a 404 error

Tags: django, urlconf

urls.py in project root

```
url(r'^people/',include('profiles.urls'))
```

profiles/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('profiles.views',
url(r'^me/$','home',name='profile_home'),
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[^/])/$','public_profile',name='user_public_profile'),
url(r'^signup/$','register_user',name='signup')
)
```

I am getting a 404 error and Django isn't able to find the Url's when I type for existing users, such as `/people/alice` while the other two patterns for the profile home and signup are working fine. Infact, this was working fine yesterday but not now, and I can't locate the problem.

The error message:

```
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
....
....    
^people/ ^me/$ [name='profile_home']
^people/ ^(?P<user_name>[^/])/$ [name='user_public_profile']
^people/ ^signup/$ [name='signup']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex pattern in the url is not correct

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[^/])/$','public_profile',name='user_public_profile'),
```

Change it to use `[\w]+`

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w]+)/$','public_profile',name='user_public_profile'),
```

Comment: When I use the regex `r'^(?P<user_name>[\w]+)/$'`, my  `r'^signup/$' is getting redirected to the 'public_profile' view rather than the `register_user` view.

Comment: @yayu, define signup url before the public profile url.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex only allows for a single character to match the username. You need to add a `+`:

```
r'^(?P<user_name>[^/]+)/$'
```